# set different background images to Ext.list in sencha touch

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm working on Sencha touch application.

I have created list view using `Ext.list` component of sencha touch.

I have set background images for all list item using CSS

```
.x-list .x-list-item {
 position: absolute !important;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height:20px;
 background: url('../images/list_1.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 97% 98%;
}
```

Now I want to set different images for different list items. Is this possible?

Comment: try .x-list-item:nth-child() for reference http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: i tried this, bad sadly doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `tpl` to generate your list items, simply give your list items a class name, something like:

```
tpl: '<div class="{bgimage}">This is list item 1.</div>'
```

then change the `bgimage` property of the `data` that you set to the list, something like this should do:

```
prepareData: function(data, index, record) {
    data.bgimage = "bg-" + index;
}
```

Then in your CSS/SASS, you can do

```
.x-list-item.bg-1 {
 background-image: url('../images/list_1.png')
}
.x-list-item.bg-2 {
 background-image: url('../images/list_2.png')
}
…
```

You could customise this to your needs, but this should get you started.

If you're using list item components (i.e. your list does not have a `tpl` config but an `itemCmp` config), just set the `cls` config on each item to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If targeting them using nth-child is not working you might have to go the more cumbersome route and attach a separate class to each list item in the html and then manipulate their background images in the CSS by changing the background property of each individually